# MyBatis: advanced result mapping

Tags: sql, mybatis

I have Entity with following structure:

```
id: 123,
key1: bla1
properties: {
  key2: bla2
}
```

And I need select such entity from DB and map it into :

```
id: 123,
properties: {
  key1: bla1
  key2: bla2
}
```

It doesn't matter if it is on the SELECT level or on resultMap (MyBatis) level.

Answer (score 2):

So the SQL is:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.key1, p.key2 FROM t1 JOIN properties p ON [join clause]
```

And the result map:

```
<resultMap id="rm">
  <id column="id", property="id">
  <association property="properties" type="">
    <result column="key1" property="key1" />
    <result column="key2" property="key2" />
  </association>
</resultMap>
```

While the result map is as follows for the 1st entity mapping, the column/property is in main object, out of association:

```
<resultMap id="rm">
  <id column="id", property="id">
  <result column="key1" property="key1" />
  <association property="properties" type="">
    <result column="key2" property="key2" />
  </association>
</resultMap>
```